Email Sending Delays in Angular Spring Boot Application
I am facing an issue with email sending delays in my Angular Spring Boot application. When I perform a certain operation and want to send a confirmation email and display an alert that the operation was successful, the process takes a noticeable amount of time due to the email sending.
Here is the relevant part of my EmailService class:


You have to make this compute intensive operation run in the background using a thread The thread will run in the background and you can return the function immediately

have you an example pleaze

check this
